# Determine which CocoaPod(s) need a specific dependency

Tags: ios, cocoapods

*Motivation: I am using XCode 7.1 Beta and some CocoaPods that are dependencies of other CocoaPods are not compatible with the beta for one reason or another. So I know which Pods are "bad" but not which Pods are using those Pods.*

Is there a `pod` command or other method to **input** a **pod name** and **output** all of its **dependents** that are included in your project *aside from trial and error*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command to list the dependencies of the library (Take `FBSDKCoreKit` as example).

```
pod spec cat FBSDKCoreKit
```

which the output is the contents of its Podspec, which contains the dependencies information:

```
{
  "name": "FBSDKCoreKit",
  "version": "4.5.1",
  "summary": "Official Facebook SDK for iOS to access Facebook Platform's core features",
  "description": "The Facebook SDK for iOS CoreKit framework provides:\n* App Events (for App Analytics)\n* Graph API Access and Error Recovery\n* Working with Access Tokens and User Profiles",
  "homepage": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/",
  "license": {
    "type": "Facebook Platform License",
    "file": "LICENSE"
  },
  "authors": "Facebook",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "7.0"
  },
  "source": {
    "git": "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git",
    "tag": "sdk-version-4.5.1"
  },
  "weak_frameworks": [
    "Accounts",
    "CoreLocation",
    "Social",
    "Security",
    "QuartzCore",
    "CoreGraphics",
    "UIKit",
    "Foundation",
    "AudioToolbox"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "Bolts": [
      "~> 1.1"
    ]
  },
  "header_dir": "FBSDKCoreKit",
  "header_mappings_dir": "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal",
  "subspecs": [
    {
      "name": "arc",
      "public_header_files": "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/*.h",
      "source_files": "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/**/*.{h,m}",
      "exclude_files": "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKDynamicFrameworkLoader.m",
      "requires_arc": true
    },
    {
      "name": "no-arc",
      "source_files": "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKDynamicFrameworkLoader.m",
      "requires_arc": false,
      "dependencies": {
        "FBSDKCoreKit/arc": [

        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Other command flags can be found [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_spec_cat).

Comment: Thanks; should I take it that this is the closest built-in function to what I need? Given some input pod, I could run this command for each pod in the project, determine the subset of pods that have the input pod in the output above, and output that subset as the "dependents" of the input pod. But there is nothing built into CocoaPods that does that?

Comment: Yes, this is the closest one.  You can read the JSON, parse it & analyze it.